# Por que o date_diff conta o meu intervalo de datas errado?

Tags: php

Nesse meu código:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$DataEntrada = new DateTime('19-10-2014');//data no formato d-m-Y
$DataSaida = new DateTime('21-10-2014');

$interval = date_diff($DataSaida, $DataEntrada);
$totalDiarias = $interval->days;

echo $totalDiarias;
```

O $totalDiarias dá 1, e não 2 como eu esperava... Por que isso ocorre?

Comment: Qual versão do php você usa?

Comment: versão do php 5.3

Comment: Parecer ser algum bug [nessa pergunta tem vários links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695870/phps-datetimediff-gets-it-wrong) relacionados, rs se você remover o time zone ele retorna 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Conforme apontado pelo @perdeu nos comentários, isto é um bug no php.
Para ajudar a sanar o problema recomendo que todos os calculos de datas no php sejam feitos usando UTC.
Deste modo ficaria algo como:

```
$DataEntrada = new DateTime('19-10-2014', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$DataSaida = new DateTime('21-10-2014', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

$interval = date_diff($DataSaida, $DataEntrada);
$totalDiarias = $interval->days;

echo $totalDiarias;
```

Quando houver necessidade de dar output dos dados, você pode mudar o timezone com a funcao [DateTime::setTimeZone()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)

```
$meuTimeZone = new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo');
$DataEntrada->setTimeZone($meuTimeZone);
echo $DataEntrada->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```

Comment: Obrigado @Kaminary ajudou demais !

Comment: @HamiltonCarmisinJunior, marque como resolvido a questão :)

Answer (score 3):

Somente acrescentando a resposta do @Kaminary, que foi super útil para o meu sistema, no sentido que pude resolver esse bug facilmente colocando o:

```
$meuTimeZone = new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo');
```

Logo abaixo das entradas POST que chegavam via XHR da comunicação com AJAX.

É importante salientar que alguns Bugs como esse são normais em todas as linguagens de programação e é essencial compartilharmos isso, pois isso serve como caso de teste para evoluir a linguagem nas próximas versões. O PHP é uma linguagem fracamente tipada, mas muito usada, fácil de apreender e com um ótimo suporte na internet (principalmente em inglês). É inclusive a que eu mais gosto dentre as que já usei.

De acordo com os links do @perdeu nos comentários da pergunta isso deve ser resolvido nas próximas versões do PHP.

Para sistemas, ou parte de sistemas, mais críticos recomendo o uso de ADA por exemplo.